# web scraping python print function

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
from lxml import html   
import requests    
import re     
import re       
url = "https://www.glassdoor.co.in/Overview/Working-at-1-800-CONTACTS-EI_IE7501.11,25.htm"        
page = requests.get(url)             
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)           
for item in tree.xpath('//div[@class="flex-aside"]'):                             
    company_name = item.xpath('.//div[@class="header cell info"]/h1/text()')              
    print company_name
```

The print function is not printing please help if there is any problem in the program
Thanks

Comment: the print function is not printing the company_name. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please format so people can copy and paste your code.

Comment: What happens if you remove the for loop? The xpath for the company name seems to work. What is that loop for?

Comment: i am scraping here from glassdoor but atleast if i have any any text value in company_name then it should get printed but it is not printing any thing and ii is not showing any error as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
company_name = tree.xpath('.//div[@class="header cell info"]/h1/text()')
print company_name[0].strip()
```

It works for me without the for loop.

Comment: but i want other things as well thats why i want to run it in a loop

Comment: Other things from the same page? I don't think you need a loop for this. Just extra `stuff_i_need = tree.xpath()`